# How to show image with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui

I've got a problem with IMG SRC. I use Angular and PhoneGap and JSON data...
I get json data img url and try

```
<img src="{{image}}">
```

It's work very good on Android 4.4.2 but any older version aren't work

This is my controller

```
$http.get('http://katalog.mirada.kz/start.php?head=json').success(function(data) {
$scope.image = data.level0.image_url;   
$scope.id_link = data.level0.id_link;
```

What's wrong in my code?

Comment: If it's working in newer Android devices but not older ones, I would run your javascript through a linter to check for any errors that maybe the newer devices ignore or fix on their own. I've had this happen a few times with using reserved words.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use `ng-src`. In cases where you are dynamically supplying the image source in Angular, the image won't render properly without it.

Comment: No result...I replace SRC on NG-SRC.
If I use SRC or NG-SRC in NG-REPEAT it's work very well..But in this question I want to use without NG-REPEAT

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are getting correct response from ajax or check it with static data  for example:$scope.image ="abc.jpg";